# How to add a dependency to a module in my Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new to Angular and am creating a project with Angular CLI. I am trying to make a rating with starts for books. I found many people telling to add a dependency to the `jkAngularRatingStars` module in the application. Following the usage steps of the documentation everything is okay, except in the following step:

> Add a dependency to the jkAngularRatingStars module in your application.
>   `angular.module('MyApp', ['jkAngularRatingStars']);`

How can I execute this step in my Angular project created with Angular CLI? I don't know where to put the dependency in the project and I don't have an instance called `angular`!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you working on below 2 version of angular?

Comment: No with lastest one (angular 6)

Comment: okk but you are using older version module jkAngularRatingStars .  angular.module('MyApp', ['jkAngularRatingStars']); this angular older version syntax. below of 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.module('MyApp', ['jkAngularRatingStars']);` is the syntax used in AngularJS to import another module and declare your own module (here named `'MyApp'`). AngularJS is not the same as Angular. Sadly, many package authors don't make the difference clear in their package name.

`angular-jk-rating-stars` is a package for AngularJS applications and therefore is incompatible with your Angular application.

Comment: Cool thanks for clarifying. I will try something else. :D